# How to measure distance between 2 points in opencv (Pixel to cm)

Tags: python, opencv, distance

Hello, I have a code that can measure the distance betweet two points, but I think the result is in pixels, so would like to get the distance, but in cm.
I'm using webcam Microsoft lifecam hd-3000, and I really don't know what to do at this point in the code.
[TEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4GnI.png)

```html
import cv2   
import numpy as np

#Captura de video a traves de la webcam
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

D = []
max_samples = 10000 

outfile = open('new.txt', 'w')
   
while(1):
        d=0.1
        centers=[]
        _, img = cap.read()
        
        hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #Se obtiene un histograma basada en las saturaciones de colores.
        
        blue_lower=np.array([95,150,100],np.uint8)
        blue_upper=np.array([150,255,255],np.uint8)
           
        blue=cv2.inRange(hsv,blue_lower,blue_upper) #Se crea una mascara utilizando intervalos de color azul.
        
        kernel = np.ones((5 ,5), "uint8") #Crea una matriz de 5x5 la cual recorrera el video,
        blue = cv2.morphologyEx(blue,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel)
        blue = cv2.morphologyEx(blue,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel)    
    
        blue=cv2.erode(blue,kernel, iterations=1) #Se erosiona utilizando el kernel sobre la mascara.
        res1=cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = blue) #La nueva imagen reemplazara a blue.
            
    
        (_,contours,hierarchy)=cv2.findContours(blue,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) #Encuentra los contornos de los objetos que se ven en el filtro
    
        for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
            area = cv2.contourArea(contour) #funcion de opencv que obtiene los contornos
            mayor_contorno = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
    
            if(area>2000):
                x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour) #Encuentra coordenadas de los contornos.
                img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
                cv2.putText(img,"Marcador",(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255,0,0))
                M = cv2.moments(contour) #Se obtiene el centro de masa de los marcadores enconrados.
                cx = int(M['m10'] /M['m00'])
                cy = int(M['m01'] /M['m00'])
                centers.append([cx,cy])
                cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
                
            if len(centers)==2:
                D = (np.linalg.norm(cx-cy)) #Se aplica distancia euclidiana para encontrar la distancia entre los centros de masa.
                print(D)
                outfile.write("{0} \n".format(D))
            
                      
        cv2.imshow("Color Tracking",img)
        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            outfile.close()
            print('Los datos han sido enviados al doctor')
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

I read about extrinsic and intrinsic parameters, but how do I get them with the webcam?
Greetings

Comment: You need to calibrate the camera. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html

Comment: You effectively need to access the projection matrix (or parameters) of the camera you're using. I don't know if OpenCV can do this without calibrating your camera. If you're camera is a commercial one, you might be able to find them by digging on the internet. Pay attention to one IMPORTANT thing though: the distance of your 2 points will be in cm on the image, not in the scene.

Comment: If I calibrate the camera https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html . May I get the parameters??